# Borrar consola desde java en linux

Tags: java

alguien sabe si hay alguna forma de lograr este efecto en la consola desde java en linux...

```
class LimpiarPantalla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            /*No hacer nada*/

        }

           /*Introduce tu código desde aquí*/

    }

}
```

Este es el código que uso para windows, pero me preguntaba como lograr que se limpie la pantalla en linux Ubuntu :c

Comment: Prueba a ver la segunda respuesta: [limpiar consola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar de esta manera:

```
public static void clear(){
    //Borrar consola en java
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) //Determina si el sistema es Windows
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();//Borrar consola Windows
        else
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear"); //Borrar consola en Linux
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Otro método que también puede servirte:

```
public static void clear() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: @LoliLover si te sirvió mí respuesta, vota positivo y marca como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: jajaj cierto se me olvido xP